# SASS::syntaxerror Undefined variable $mq-m-max

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the error SASS::syntaxerror Undefined variable $mq-m-max when trying to include sass file in my ruby project.

I renamed the file application.css to application.scss, so here is my application.scss :

```
@import "abstracts/variables"; 
@import "abstracts/_mixins";
```

My file _variables.scss :

```
$mq-a:                    360px;
$mq-s:                    414px;
$mq-t-max:                767px;
$mq-t:                    768px;
$mq-m-max:                999px;  // 1023px;
$mq-m:                    1000px; // 1024px;
$mq-ml-max:               1279px;
$mq-ml:                   1280px;
// $mq-l:                 1400px; // Not revelant now
$mq-l:                    1600px;
$mq-xl:                   1920px;
```

and my file _mixins.scss :

```
@mixin mq($size: m, $max: false) {
  @if $size == t {
    @if $max {
      @media (max-width: $mq-t-max) {
        @content;
      }
    } @else {
      @media (min-width: $mq-t) {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
  @else if $size == m {
    @if $max {
      @media (max-width: $mq-m-max) {
        @content;
      }
    } @else {
      @media (min-width: $mq-m) {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
```

and my gemfile :

```
ruby '2.6.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

#Contentful 
gem 'contentful', '~> 2.14'

#contentful rails 
gem 'contentful_rails', '~> 0.5.0'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I don't get why it doesn't work, the variables are call before the mixins. In my application.scss the path to _mixins and _variables work well

Comment: You use `@import "abstracts/variables"` but your file is named `_variables.scss`. Have you tried `@import "abstracts/_variables"`?

Comment: Yep, I tried both, with and without underscore and I have the same error

Comment: I found ! I needed to add jquery and boostrap-sass to my gemfile : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/